# Function overloading example used on typescript docs

Tags: typescript

I was reading the TypeScript handbook and I stopped on the section [**Writing Good Overloads**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#writing-good-overloads).

They say:

> This function is fine; we can invoke it with strings or arrays.
> However, we can’t invoke it with a value that might be a string or an
> array, because TypeScript can only resolve a function call to a single
> overload

```
function len(s: string): number;
function len(arr: any[]): number;
function len(x: any) {
  return x.length;
}
```

```
len(""); // OK
len([0]); // OK
len(Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hello" : [0]); // Compiler error, see the error below
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(s: string): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number[] | "hello"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(arr: any[]): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number[] | "hello"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGwKZgBQGcBcitQBOMYA5gJR5ggC2ARqoQNwBQoksCK6GAhoYTy8wATwDaAXUqJq9Rq3bR4SNJgAeQ0eUQBvFokSFUUEISRqAdKtJQAFqwC%20LVRgBEr8k0QB6b4gDyANLOPGIADFJevgHBLgCyvHYWhMIAJnA0GNoAfIhhFgCsiAD8iK62qMjIcK6IeOGRQA)

And they resolved the code by saying, you can get rid of this error by using a union type instead:

```
function len(x: any[] | string) {
  return x.length;
}
```

Why? Why was the compiler able to accept the function calls:

```
len(""); // OK
len([0]); // OK
```

but refused this:

```
len(Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hello" : [0]); // Compiler error
```

Why did it refuse it when it is valid? Is this related to the current version of TypeScript but might be changed in the future?

Comment: The quote says why: _"because TypeScript can only resolve a function call to a single overload"_. The value is inferred as `number[] | "hello"` which, while each separate type in the union could be resolved to a single overload, cannot _itself_ be resolved to either of them (not to `string` because it could be an array, and not to `any[]` because it also could _not_ be an array).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why?

Because there is no overload defined as taking a parameter of type `string | number[]`, but that's the type of the result of the expression `Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hello" : [0]`. Neither the `string` nor the `any[]` overload matches, because the `string` overload can't accept `any[]`, and the `any[]` overload can't accept `string`. (In contrast, the other examples give arguments of type `string` [which matches the first overload] or `number[]` [which matches the second].)

You could *add* an overload that supported that expression if you wanted:

```typescript
// You wouldn't really do this, but for illustration:
function len(s: string): number;
function len(arr: any[]): number;
function len(arrOrString: string | any[]): number; // <===
function len(x: any) {
    return x.length;
}
```

In this specific case, as they said, if you wanted to support that type you wouldn't use overloading at all, you'd just use `function len(x: string | any[])` directly, but hopefully seeing that the third overload fixes the error helps you understand the error.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGwKZgBQGcBcitQBOMYA5gJR5ggC2ARqoQNwBQoksCK6GAhoYTy8wATwDaAXUqJq9Rq3bR4SNJn6EA8oQDKREqTwFiZRAB9Ew8VKq0GzRAHoHiADwBeD23BKuqjAA8hUXJEAG8WREjEQlQoEEIkfwA6VVIoAAtWAF8WFj8AWV4MpMJhABM4GgwQgD5EAAYkgFZEAH5EACJ01GRkOA7EPDF6qSZHZwBhSoAHGDRCREZCOEIAGnxUVEQMraWVxAY+gHcgA)

> Is this related to the current version of TypeScript but might be changed in the future?

Almost certainly not, it would be a breaking change (which the TypeScript project tries very hard to avoid), and there wouldn't be much point to it (since you can just define the overload, or define the function as a non-overloaded function accepting `string | any[]`).

---

Side note: I **think** you know this based on the question, but just in case: Remember that the *implemention signature* is not directly accessible. There is no available `len(x: any)` signature. When you use function overloads, only the overload signatures, not the implementation signature, is available. Details in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#function-overloads).